# node js uploading image with multer and save to firebase storage

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage, ejs

My ejs front end code is as below

```
<form action='/powerLink' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'> <input type='file' name='file'> <input type='submit' value='fileupload'> </form>
```

and my js code where receive file is as below

```
var storagee=firebase.storage().ref("test");
 app.post("/powerLink", multer.single('file'),function(req,res){
  let file = req.file;
  if(file){
    console.log(file);
     storage.put(file);
  }
```

when I console.log(file)
it has value like below
{ fieldname: '

```
file',
  originalname: 'appiicon.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  buffer:
   <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 00 e1 00 00 00 e1 08 06 00 00 00 3e b3 d2 7a 00 00 00 19 74 45 58 74 53 6f 66 74 77 61 72 65 00 ... >,
  size: 15966 }
```

I thought it save right to my storage and folder "test" and then save image to that folder. but nothing happened.

I can't guess what's the reason of not uploading image file to storage on firebase

Comment: You dont need the multer package you can bypass the multer middleware and directly upload the file to firebase. Also if you are using multer you need to use the uploaded file location. More details are on different functions are on - https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

Comment: You don't need multer for uploading files to firebase storage.

Comment: if not using multer, how can I send file to js to upload to firebase?

Comment: I think there are way less functions in the firebase admin package for NodeJS than for the web, for the browser you can upload `base64`, `data url`, the file obtained from the `FileReader API`

Answer (score 4):

I've done this before using the firebase admin sdk with something like this (typescript):

```
async function uploadFile(file: Express.Multer.File, directory: string, fileName: string): Promise<string> {
  const bucket = firebaseAdmin.storage().bucket();
  const fullPath = `${directory}/${fileName}`;
  const bucketFile = bucket.file(fullPath);

  await bucketFile.save(file.buffer, {
    contentType: file.mimetype,
    gzip: true
  });

  const [url] = await bucketFile.getSignedUrl({
    action: "read",
    expires: "01-01-2050"
  });

  return url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a related issue. Passing in the file object returned the error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined**

Rather than passing in the file object, you should pass in the buffer property like this:

```
var storagee=firebase.storage().ref("test");
app.post("/powerLink", multer.single('file'),function(req,res){
    var file = req.file;
    if(file){
    console.log(file);
    let metadata = {contentType: file.mimetype, name: file.originalname}
    storage.put(file.buffer, metadata);
}
```

After this, I got an XMLHttpRequest error. I installed the xhr2 module. https://github.com/pwnall/node-xhr2

```
npm install xhr2
```

Then if you have to access the storage in multiple files you can add the code in your index/main file

```
global.XMLHttpRequest = require("xhr2");
```